# R Summarize and calculate mean for logical variable

Tags: r, group-by, boolean

I have dataset that contains logical variable ('verdad') and a group variable ('group') that splits all data into several groups. Now I would like to summarize the data and calculate mean of the logical variable to test the hypothesis that occurence of TRUE and FALSE values in 'verdad' column differs accross the groups. The code is as simple as this:

```
domy_nad_1000 %>% 
  filter(usable_area > 1000) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mean(verdad, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The datatype of 'verdad' is logical but it is showing this error:

```
In mean.default(., verdad, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It should be `summarise(verdad = mean(verdad, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to wrap your `mean` in a `summarize` function.

```
domy_nad_1000 %>% 
  filter(usable_area > 1000) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(verdad_mean = mean(verdad, na.rm = TRUE))
```